# What is the meaning of phrase "were on top of your paperwork"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

> I was anxious to hear about Theodore Nott and -- thought I'd check
> whether you'd kept your promise and were on top of your paperwork.

What is the meaning of phrase "were on top of your paperwork"?
It is from "Harry Potter and the Cursed Child". May anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It could mean at least two different things, but, in this context, it means "up to date with your paperwork."

Answer (score 1):

To be "on top of" a job or task means that you have the situation under control, you are succeeding at it. So to be "on top of your paperwork" means that you have your paperwork filled out correctly, are on schedule processing it, etc.